# How to protect window.opener.location

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am using `window.open` to open a new window which will send some message to the parent window using `window.opener.postMessage`.

This child window URL is arbitrary. I mean there is a textbox where the users can give the URL and it will be opened using `window.open`.

Although the user is suspected to use the URLs that are supported, it is also possible that some random URL will be used. In this case, I don't want to child window to make any changes to the parent window, especially to the parent location.

How can I avoid this issue? I've tried to use `noreferrer,noopener`; however, that breaks entire cross-window communication altogether, which is not desired.

Comment: You can check the event's origin in your `message` event handler, eg: `window.addEventListener('message', (event) => { if(event.origin === 'https://safe.host'){..} })`.

Comment: This is not what I am talking about. In the child window, malicious javascript can simple do `window.opener.location = "https://www.badurl.com"`, which I don't want to happen while making sure that I can send `window.opener.postMessage() `is working.